# How to let the user know that his task will be repeated? (any better way of doing that?)

Tags: checkboxes, dates

I'm creating an application where users can send tasks to others by email. I have a scenario when a user can send a task right now, or he can specify recurring time. It looks like this (with the big "Send" button below):

[image: First case]

Let's assume we perform this action at 9:30AM in the morning. Let's see another use case:

[image]

Here we want to repeat this task every day at 10:00AM. But if we specify two options, the task will be sent twice. And we want to let the user know about it.

Is there any better ways of letting user know about that? Or may be there could be better UI for this task?

Thank you.

Comment: ¿What is the default behaviour if the user does not check 'Send Now'? Generally, one notification per task would be appropriate, any more would be spam.

Comment: So why don't you just ignore the repeat for the current day?

Answer (score 1):

How do you set to repeat the task? If you have a UI, you can probably have an option to select start date.

[image: Outlook Appointment Recurrence screen]

Answer (score 1):

I may be interpreting the question wrong, but wouldn't the send now just be a button? No checkbox? What is the case for having nothing checked and clicking send? What would happen then?

I would get rid of the 'send now' checkbox (just have the repeat checkbox) and use a button that says 'send now' by default, this way the user can just send it now without repeating... if the user selects the 'repeat...' checkbox, update the button to just say 'send'. This would eliminate the need for any messaging and the the task would never be sent twice.